# Decrypt each element of an Array

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I've got an array of `n` string elements encrypted with `CryptoJS` : `[krypt1, krypt2, krypt3, ...]`

**The `keydecrypt` is the same for each element.**

I try to decrypt each element of the array and return an array of string decrypted elements like this `[dekrypt1, dekrypt2, dekrypt3, ...]`

My code is:

```
var urltodecrypt = this.url.chunk;
function decrypteach(x) {
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(x.toString(), keydecrypt).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
var clearfileurl = urltodecrypt.map(decrypteach);
```

When there is 1 element in the array, everything's fine: it return an array of rightly decrypted string element.

When there is >1 elements, `var urltodecrypt` give still the right array (verified), **but `var clearfileurl` return an error: `Error: Malformed UTF-8 data`**

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Tried on @vector advices a `loop over each element function` on [this model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/7281870) :

```
var urltodecrypt = this.url.chunk;
var arrayLength = urltodecrypt.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     var clearfileurl = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(urltodecrypt.toString(), keydecrypt).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
console.log (clearfileurl);
```

Exact same result = 1 element array :ok / >1 elements array: `Error: Malformed UTF-8 data`

**EDIT #2: question close**

I just broke my first code (`map`) into different vars :

- `x.toString()`
- `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()`
- `toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)`

I relaunched my server : everything's fine now, from 1 element array to +10 elements array.

Just in case, below my (heavy & superstitious...) tested working code:

```
var urltodecrypt = this.url.chunk;
console.log (urltodecrypt);
function decrypteach(x) {
    var stringurl = x.toString();
    var bytesfileurl = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(stringurl, keydecrypt);
    var finaldecrypturl = bytesfileurl.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return finaldecrypturl;
}
var clearfileurl = urltodecrypt.map(decrypteach);
console.log (clearfileurl);
```

Comment: You've provided the code, but haven't shown what's supposed to be wrong with it. Please [edit] your question provide example inputs, outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Are you looping over the array elements or feeding the entire array into decrypteach() all at once?

Comment: @vector, that question is answered by the code: `map`.

Comment: @vector feeding the entire array into decrypteach() all at once

Comment: first of, your code does not show where [dekrypt1, dekrypt2, dekrypt3, ...] is initialised. looks like you need to loop over the array and return one decrypted element at a time, that's why it works for you when you have 1 element in the array and not 2 or more. so, call the decrypt function once for each array element or loop over them in the function and return array of decrypted items, no?

Comment: @vector Could you provide a example of loop over each element function?

Comment: Look at the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @vector I edited my question on your advices: same result with a loop function.

Comment: create a codepen or a jsfiddle of what you've done. at this point, we need to see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @vector There is no need to create a codepen or jsfiddle. Stack Overflow has the same functionality.

Comment: @vector & others : finally 'made' my code work in the `mapping` way - see edit #2.